How to bypass google frp on samsung a7lite T225N with latest Android 14 update that ends in XH2
I want to fix this problem as the past owner is no longer contactable and I wish to bypass the google frp
I used odin and samflash but it has been patched, I also used talkback and emergency method but it has also been patched

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
